# How to open device setting form flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, settings

I want to open the setting when the user taps the button.

I can see the intent `Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS` defined for the setting [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Settings)

I am using the package `Android_intent`

code:

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
   action: 'Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS',
 );
await intent.launch();
```

But, I am getting the error:-

```
E/flutter (14266): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS (has extras) }, null)
```

How to open the setting page form flutter?

Answer (score 4):

I was using the wrong Setting intent,
following is working
code:-

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'android.settings.SETTINGS',
);
await intent.launch();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *app_settings*.

```
onPressed: () {
          AppSettings.openDeviceSettings(
            asAnotherTask: true,
          );
        },
```

Should work both Android and iOS.

Read more: https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this plugin

`app_settings: 3.0.1`

then import it

`import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';`

and then I use

```
onPressed() {
  AppSettings.openDataRoamingSettings(); //or whatever settings you want to open xD
}
```

Do tell if it works :)